# What does **long** mean here?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

> The dust was **long** in settling back again.

It's easy to guess the meaning of  **long** as used by Steinbeck in GoW, but could anyone please link a similar dictionary usage? I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the regular "Having a large duration", but in a rather poetic syntax.

For comparison, look at the idiom

> [the deal has been] *long in the making*.

Which means that it took a long time to make the deal.